# Cabal: File in tar archive is not in the expected directory

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have been unable to install any packages using Cabal, getting an error saying that the tar archive is not in the expected directory.  For example, if I try to do, `cabal install mtl`, I get the following error:

> Resolving dependencies...
>   Failed to install text-1.2.1.1
>   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   text-1.2.1.1 failed while unpacking the package. The exception was:
>   user error (File in tar archive is not in the expected directory. Expected:
>   "." but got the following hierarchy: ["text-1.2.1.1"])

I have run `cabal update`, and `cabal --version` gives the following:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.5.0 
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?  Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That version of cabal-install had a big making it almost completely unusable. Upgrading should solve this problem.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Anyone else having a similar problem, will need to download the source for cabal from [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html).  Doing `cabal install cabal-install` will end up giving you the same errors that I mentioned in my question.  Thanks